# Adding multiple numericupdown values to a label

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am currently doing a college assignment and need a little help with the coding side of it. I am making a form regarding an ash grove case study.

I am new to C# and prefer html.

I need help knowing how to make code so i can change the numeric updown value of different options and it will add the price up.

Image of what my form looks like:
[image]
For example say i want drontal for 1 small dog and antibiotics for 7 days. how would i get it so it will add the values into the label and storing them?

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Task3
{

    public partial class Medication : Form
    {
        public Medication()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Exit button
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Previous button
        {
            Form Start = new ClientData();
            this.Hide();
            Start.Show();
        }

        private void btnNextForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Next button
        {
            Form Start = new Procedures();
            this.Hide();
            Start.Show();
        }

        private void UpdownAntibiotic7_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownAntibiotic14_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownFleeAndMite_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownHeartworm_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownAnesGasTo30min_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownAnesGasAfter30min_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownFentanyl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdownFrontline_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownAnalgesia_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownBaytrill_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownMetronidazole_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownRimadyl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownDrontalSmall_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownDrontalLarge_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpDownCanineRabies_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am using visual studio 2017

updated version of code. No idea what I am doing wrong.

```
private decimal Calculate(int count, string nudName)
        {
            decimal price;
            decimal result = 0;

            switch (nudName)
            {
                case "UpdownAntibiotic7":
                    price = 19.60m;
                    result = price * count;
                    break;

                case 
                    // ...add more cases for different medicines

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void UpdownAntibiotic7_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(price.Text))
                price.Text = (Calculate(Convert.ToInt32(UpdownAntibiotic7.Value), UpdownAntibiotic7.Name)).ToString();
            else
               price.Text = (decimal.Parse(price.Text.Replace(' ', '0').Replace('£', '0')) + Calculate(Convert.ToInt32(UpdownAntibiotic7.Value), UpdownAntibiotic7.Name)).ToString("C");
        }
```

Comment: what you have done so far? show the code

Comment: Also I would like to add, since you seem to prefer html, try to make your assignment in WPF instead of the old WinForms. WPF uses XAML and is much more compareable to HTML. You can set the properties with MVVM and it runs much smoother. Depending on the needs of your application ofcoures.

Comment: We have to use visual studio as it is a requirement for an assignment you can find my code here https://pastebin.com/2E2iQA0t

Comment: @ReganCurr WPF is a forms type within Visual Studio. Also you should use Ctrl+K and copy paste the code within your question.Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your solution needs to be something like: on the applicable event read the control values, perform your calculation and then do something with the result. The first part should be easy (each control instance has a `Value` property. The second is: just write the code. The third is far to broad without details of how you want it stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we will declare an `int` variable for each `NumericUpAndDown` to store the *old* `SelectedValue` of the `NumericUpAndDowns`, so that we know if we either have to add or subtract the money value.

```
int nudAntibioticOldValue; // should be declared above the constructor
```

Furthermore you have to subscribe to the `ValueChanged` event of the `numericUpDowns` so you get notified once the user changed their value. In the event you will set the text of your label `laTotalPrice`. First you get the existing text in the label and parse it to `decimal`, so you can calculate with the already existing value.

```
private void nudAntibiotic_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(laTotalPrice.Text))
        laTotalPrice.Text = (Calculate(Convert.ToInt32(nudAntibiotic.Value), nudAntibiotic.Name)).ToString();
    else
        laTotalPrice.Text = (decimal.Parse(laTotalPrice.Text.Replace(' ', '0').Replace('€','0')) + Calculate(Convert.ToInt32(nudAntibiotic.Value), nudAntibiotic.Name)).ToString("C");

        nudAntibioticOldValue = Convert.ToInt32(nudAntibiotic.Value);
    }
```

After that you add to it the new value, which will get calculated in `Calculate()`. As method parameter you enter the `Value` of the `numericUpDown` and the `Name` of the `numericUpDown`, so you can use the name for a `switch case` statement. That you can differ between different cases with different prices for each medicine.

```
private decimal Calculate(int count, string nudName)
{
    decimal price;
    decimal result = 0;

    switch (nudName)
    {
        case "nudAntibiotic":
            count -= nudAntibioticOldValue;
            price = 19.60m;
            result = price * count;
            break;

        //...add other cases for different medicine

        default:
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I updated the answer to use `decimal` instead of `int`, since the only purpose of the invention of `decimal` is it's use for e.g. exactly *this* scenario here.

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

According to the [MSDN Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal).

Comment: Price as int is not a good practice, use double or decimal instead.

Comment: I know but that is no big deal, it can be easily adjusted. I just showed him a structure he can work with.

Comment: He's a new programmer, and though your code looks splendid, I think you'll need to learn him the basics first.

Comment: In my opinion this is some part of the basics. The beginning of `C#`.

Comment: Upvoted the edited answer and deleted my own, this will do nicely.

Comment: I have followed your Switch method and it comes up with an error of System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' (I dont know how to format correctly yet still learning that to)

Comment: The `string` you set in the `case` has to be exactly the name of the `numericUpAndDown` control. I guess you entered not exactly the correct name of the control. For your first `numericUpAndDown` you need to set the `case` as `"UpdownAntibiotic7"`.

Comment: I have just gotten back off lunch and i followed what you have said. I have no errors when compiling. but when i change the value of the numupdown box i get a error of <code> "input string was not in a correct format" </code> ( i have no idea how to format correctly, any help on that to?)

Comment: @Regan I edited my answer. I changed the line below the `else` statement. `.ToString("C")` gets your rid of the trailing zeros and the `.Replace()` parts replaces the spaces and the *currency sign*. Please enter there your *pound* sign instead of the *euro* sign or to whatever currency you want to use. There are some other mistakes, wait. I will fix that as well. I will message you once this solutions works perfect.

Comment: okay thanks @L.Guthardt I have updated my code with what I have put in (see main question). Am i doing anything wrong? and thanks for all of your help so far.

Comment: Your welcome, we all need to help each other, especially beginners. I updated all the code. Now it works like a charm and adds or subtracts the money value on instant `numericUpAndDown.ValueChanged()`.

Comment: I have followed all of the steps and tried multiple different names and I am still having trouble getting it to work. I have sent you an email instead of us trying to continue this discussion here. Just hope that was the right email address.

Comment: Yes you send it to the right email. I will have a look at it and message/email you.

Comment: @Regan Please send me the code of your `Medication.Designer.cs` file as an email. I have an idea what the issue can be.